# How to send POST request with cookie on a remote server using java

Tags: java, post, httpclient, session-cookies, setcookie

I need to get data from a Web page and for that i need to keep session alive(i think so),So when i enter username password through browser to website ,i run my code,which takes cookies from my browser and sends post request with cookies attached to the page who's data i want to get

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpURLConnection class provided by java. Do somethink like this:-

```
URL url = new URL("You URL");
HttpURLConnection hCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
hCon.setDoOutput(true);
hCon.setRequestMethod("POST");
hcon.setRequestProperty("Cookie", myCookie);
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(
hpCon.getOutputStream());
out.close()
```

and than try to read the response.

You can also give a look into [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/)

Comment: can u tell me how to get the source code from the URL using response.when i m using System.out.println(httpcon.getResponseCode());//prints 200
   System.out.println(httpcon.getResponseMessage())//prints ok

Comment: what is the data that you need and from which website.